# Set the height and width of a mpld3 plot

Tags: matplotlib, mpld3

I want to set the width and height of a mpld3 plot to a specific value (in pixels, so it fits the div it is in). The way I tried it looks like this (javascript):

```
commands["width"]=plotWidth;
commands["height"]=plotHeight;
mpld3.draw_figure("plotname",commands);
```

plotWidth and plotHeight the values I want the height and width to be set to.

Now, this actually sets the size of the mpld3-figure object to the values I want, but the plot inside still keeps its old size, so it looks like nothing happened.
So, how do I change the size of the plot itself? So far it looks like whatever I do, the plot does not change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the shape of an `mpld3` plot when creating a figure with the python code `plt.figure(figsize=(width,height))` (where `width` and `height` are in inches).  Here is a [notebook demonstrating this](https://gist.github.com/aflaxman/d9485fd54130cf83f567).

There has been [some interest in making `mpld3` figures "responsive"](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/issues/234), which would be a cooler and more precise way to accomplish your goal, but so far no one has tried making the necessary code changes.  Patches welcome!